# Does grappling cause bludgeoning damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, grapple, unarmed-combat, damage-types

According to the [grapple](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#grapple) rules in the SRD:

> ...you deal damage to the target as if with an [unarmed strike](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#unarmedStrike).

When you look at the weapons table for unarmed strike you see:

[image: unarmed attacks]

Would that mean grappling does bludgeoning damage?

This might seem like a trivial question, but we're experiencing disagreement on this point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, of course. That's exactly what it's saying.

Comment: I realize this question borderlines ridiculousness, but I asked it to get someone to 'see, I'm not the only one that says so.'

Comment: @Ruut Fair enough! That's useful context information to put in the question. I added that to the question — but if you could elaborate on what the argument against is, I can elaborate in this answer on the argument for, tailoring it to the difficulty you're trying to solve.

Comment: A fellow player, I am not DM'ing for a change, is telling the DM that grappling damage is un-typed and therefore not subject to damage reduction effects. I told him that it deals damage according to unarmed strike. His argument is based on "as if" meaning "similar but not the same." I told him he was reading way too deep into things that don't exist.